# Stanford NLP 3.5.1 no class as StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I was using Stanford NLP version 3.2.0 with java, using the core jar and the model jar.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

I moved to the version 3.5.1 today and imported both jar files for that version and now StanfordCoreNLP get highlighted in my Netbeans project and there is no class for that.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Version 3.5.1 requires Java 8, version 3.2.0 works with Java 7. I suppose your project uses Java 7.

Comment: I upgraded to Java 8 but it still says: **cannot find symbol StanfordCoreNLP**

Comment: Is there a specific reason you upgraded? Can you go back to the prior version? I use the not-most-recent version because I don't want to switch to Java 8, personally.

Comment: I want to use the latest Stanford Core NLP

Comment: @blueygh2 I uninstalled java 8 and my old Netbeans 6. , re-installed the new java with Netbeans package, now it works! Your answer was helpful, without it I would be searching for a solution all over the internet!